# How to backup programs without risking to restore into a corrupt system

Tags: windows-7, backup, reinstall, windows-backup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Backup an installed software](https://superuser.com/questions/483014/backup-an-installed-software)

I have a newly installed SSD in my system (with OS etc installed on it), but I'm not too happy with the boot up time (1 min 15 s). So I am planning to look over the BIOS settings (mainly thinking of setting AHCI-mode for my SSD) and then make a clean install to see if that helps things out.

I do however have a whole lot of programs, custom settings (registry changes etc) and custom drivers installed, and the thought of reinstalling all these is not very tempting. There for I want to make a backup that I can use after the clean install to get all these back. (All my files, media and such, are on a secondary drive - no need to back them up).

However I am a little bit worried that restoring my system from a complete system image will result in a corrupt system. Like if I change something in BIOS that is critical for example. A clean install of Windows 7 would be fully working, since it adapts into the current configuration. But if I then restore to a complete system image of my earlier system I am afraid that it would behave like if I did these changes to BIOS without any reinstall.

So: is there a way to backup and restore all my programs (and preferably drivers too) without risking of restoring into a corrupt system?

If it is possible with the built in windows backup/restore I am glad, but of course third party programs works as well.

Thanks!

Comment: @Karan IMO it should not be a dupe of that as its about **backup from corrupt drive** while the other post is asking for only backup.

Comment: @avirk: He doesn't want to restore a full system image since that will simply bring his system back to the way it is now (i.e. corrupted). His *actual* question is about how he can backup and restore all his programs and drivers to a fresh Windows install (that will no longer be corrupted). Thus this question does seem to be a duplicate of the one I linked to.

Comment: @Karan, Avirk Actually, is the question not "can BIOS settings prevent my back up succeeding?". I think the use of "corrupt" in OP title is wrong, it should be *non-compatible*. I have closed being off topic, this is a mistake as should be "not a real question" as it's not clear as to what is being asked!

Answer (score 0):

You can backup the whole drive to a file (and restore it from one) using programs such as Norton ghost, [CloneZilla](http://clonezilla.org/), [Acronis True Image](http://www.acronis.co.uk/) etc. etc.

However just changing a BIOS setting should not change anything in the OS. Worst case it will not boot anymore and you will have to revert the BIOS change.

As for AHCI:

1. Yes, do enabled it. Esp. with an SSD.
2. Do it in the right sequence: 1) enable AHCI drivers. 2) Shutdown. 3) Change BIOS setting to AHCI. 4) Boot succesfully.

For more details, search this site for posts such as these: 
[should-ahci-be-enabled-for-an-ssd](http://superuser.com/questions/466254/should-ahci-be-enabled-for-an-ssd)

Comment: Looks like he wants to backup and restore only programs without completely imaging the system, which is obviously not possible.